# Problem with WiFi card after running sudo apt-update && sudo apt upgrade -y

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, upgrade

Some context; I had a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 a few days ago. Was having a network card problem but I fixed it by downloading a newer version of the driver by running

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1 --all
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtl8821ce/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i rtl8821*.deb
```

Today I decide to run an update by running

```
sudo apt-update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

I rebooted my system sometime later and when it turned on I noticed I was having the same WiFi adapter problem I was having before the upgrade. Wondering if I need to undo the upgrade. [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KkjVfNfzGs/) is a paste of all the packages I had installed that day. I'm sure the second entry was for the `sudo apt upgrade -y` command; I included the first entry because it was installed the same day I assume it had to be part of that update (I installed no other packages).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just need to run `sudo dpkg -i rtl8821*.deb` again for the new kernel you downloaded.

Comment: Did not work. I get back
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rtl8821ce-dkms:
rtl8821ce-dkms depends on dkms (>= 2.1.0.0); however:
Package dkms is not installed.

Comment: @xvymnp so install the package?  `sudo apt install dkms`.  Alternatively use `sudo apt install ./rtl8821*.deb` which invokes apt/apt-get and its dependency resolver - `dpkg` is not capable of dependency resolution, that's where apt comes in.